# Wifi not working on hp pavilion 17 g 150na with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, hp

I am trying to switch from windows 10 to Ubuntu 16.04, but I'm having issues with the wifi. It doesn't show the wireless connections, but just the ethernet ones. How can I fix it?

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01) 
DeviceName: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11 b/g/n 1x1Wi-Fi + BT4.0 M.2 
Combo Adapter Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a] 
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)